# Parse JSON String from URL

Tags: android, json

I am developing an Android Application using an AsyncTask class to get the JSON from an URL.

The variable Content prints all the JSON raw code and I want it divided so I can put all the data in the JSON in different TextViews.

#### Base1i0.class

```
package info.androidhive.slidingmenu;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Base1i0 extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.base1_0);

        String serverURL = "JSON URL";
        new LongOperation().execute(serverURL);
    }

    private class LongOperation  extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        private final HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        private String Content;
        private String Error = null;
        private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(Base1i0.this);

        TextView descripciocat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewidioma);

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            descripciocat.setText("Output : ");
            Dialog.setMessage("Carregant informació");
            Dialog.show();
        }

        protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {
                // Server url call by GET method
                HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                Content = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                Error = e.getMessage();
                cancel(true);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Error = e.getMessage();
                cancel(true);
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            Dialog.dismiss();

            if (Error != null) {
                descripciocat.setText("Output : "+ Error);
            } else {
                descripciocat.setText("Output : "+ Content);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### JSON code

```
[{
        "id":"1",
        "cox":"11111",
        "coy":"22222",
        "tip":"aaaaa",
        "dca":"bbbbb",
        "des":"ccccc",
        "den":"ddddd",
        "dfr":"eeeee",
        "dde":"fffff",
        "hca":"ggggg",
        "hes":"hhhhh",
        "hen":"iiiii",
        "hfr":"jjjjj",
        "hde":"kkkkk",
        "adr":"lllll",
        "tel":"mmmmm",
        "fax":"nnnnn",
        "web":"ooooo",
        "nif":"ppppp",
        "pob":"qqqqq",
        "ext":"rrrrr",
        "pja":"sssss",
        "com":"ttttt",
        "sup":"uuuuu",
        "nur":"vvvvv",
        "urb":"wwwww",
        "urba":"xxxx",
        "sse":"yyyyy",
        "ind":"zzzzz",
        "con":"33333",
        "sag":"44444",
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That JSON is an **array of objects**, containing **only 1 object** with 31 attributes.

To create a JsonArray from a string you can do : `JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(string)`.

To get the first JSONObject from an array you can do `JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(0)`

To get attributes from the object you can do `String content = obj.getString("cox")` and so on.

Answer (score -1):

You will first have to deserialize the JSON string using [`GSON`](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

> Gson is a Java library that can be used to convert Java Objects into
>   their JSON representation. It can also be used to convert a JSON
>   string to an equivalent Java object. Gson can work with arbitrary Java
>   objects including pre-existing objects that you do not have
>   source-code of.

Once you do that, you can use it to populate different `TextView`s.

[Mykong's post](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/) is a good starting point.